# How to calculate Heart Rate Counts from ECG/PPG sensor(AFE49I30 sensor)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I really know how to calculate Heart rate BPM using PPG/ECG sensor I am trying the below code and also give some new updates in answer.

I am trying to calculate my Heart Rate using a PPG/ECG sensor ***(I am using an AFE49I30 sensor)*** using the Xamarin form Application.

- I have one Bluetooth device and the Bluetooth device is connected to the Xamarin form Application using Plugin.BLE package.
- After connection, I am getting all services and service of characteristics of the Bluetooth device.
- After getting the characteristics of PPG/ECG. I am getting a byte array of PPG/ECG. Now, what can I do to get the Heart Rate count from this byte array?

Below Shown some screenshots of my code to get a bytes array of my Heart rate.

- PPG getting bytes array data using this code:

[image]

```
public async void GetPPGLiveData()
        {
            if (App.device != null)
            {
                var temp = App.DeviceDetailsModel.FirstOrDefault(a => a.DeviceService.Id.StartsWith("00005c00"));
                var PPGservices = await App.device.GetServiceAsync(new Guid(temp.DeviceService.Id));

                if (PPGservices != null)
                {
                    var PPGcharacter = temp.DeviceServiceCharacs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.StartsWith("00005c02"));
                    var PPGList = await PPGservices.GetCharacteristicAsync(new Guid(PPGcharacter.Id));

                    PPGList.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
                    {
                        var receivedBytes = args.Characteristic.Value;

                        Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                        {
                           //Need to write some Heart Rate calculation Logic.
                            
                        });
                    };
                    await PPGList.StartUpdatesAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

- ECG getting bytes array data using this code:
  [image]

```
public async void GetECGLiveData()
        {
            if (App.device != null)
            {
                var temp = App.DeviceDetailsModel.FirstOrDefault(a => a.DeviceService.Id.StartsWith("00005c00"));
                var ECGservices = await App.device.GetServiceAsync(new Guid(temp.DeviceService.Id));

                if (ECGservices != null)
                {
                    var ECGcharacter = temp.DeviceServiceCharacs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.StartsWith("00005c01"));
                    var ECGList = await ECGservices.GetCharacteristicAsync(new Guid(ECGcharacter.Id));

                    ECGList.ValueUpdated += (o, args) =>
                    {
                        var receivedBytes = args.Characteristic.Value;

                        Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
                        {

                            //Need to Write Some calculation logic here.
                        });
                    };
                    await ECGList.StartUpdatesAsync();
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: Please use actual code, rather than images of your code.

Comment: Do not use `async void` unless it's an event handler. Make it `async Task`. Though that may not solve this specific problem, it might prevent others.

Comment: As for the interpretation of the bytes read: You need to refer to the manual of the respective devices. Every manufacturer may have their own protocol. Maybe even on a model-basis.

Comment: you will have to build a stream and check with the vendor details whether it might even be compressed etc.

Comment: While the other comments are correct that you need to check with the vendor to determine what format the data is in, did you try just reading the array as a string to see what happened? Something like `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recievedBytes, 0, recievedBytes.Length);`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to Implement the R-R algorithm. I am using below logic code.

[image]

```
internal static HeartRateReading ReadBuffer(byte[] buffer, int length)
    {
        if (length == 0) return null;

        var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, length);
        var flags = (HeartRateFlags)ms.ReadByte();
        var isshort = flags.HasFlag(HeartRateFlags.IsShort);
        var contactSensor = (ContactSensorStatus)(((int)flags >> 1) & 3);
        var hasEnergyExpended = flags.HasFlag(HeartRateFlags.HasEnergyExpended);
        var hasRRInterval = flags.HasFlag(HeartRateFlags.HasRRInterval);
        var minLength = isshort ? 3 : 2;

        if (buffer.Length < minLength) return null;

        var reading = new HeartRateReading
        {
            Flags = flags,
            Status = contactSensor,
            BeatsPerMinute = isshort ? ReadUInt16(ms) : ms.ReadByte()
        };

        if (hasEnergyExpended)
        {
            reading.EnergyExpended = ReadUInt16(ms);
        }

        if (hasRRInterval)
        {
            var rrvalueCount = (buffer.Length - ms.Position) / sizeof(ushort);
            var rrvalues = new int[rrvalueCount];
            for (var i = 0; i < rrvalueCount; ++i)
            {
                rrvalues[i] = ReadUInt16(ms);
            }

            reading.RRIntervals = rrvalues;
        }

        return reading;
    }
    public static ushort ReadUInt16(Stream stream)
    {
        return (ushort)(stream.ReadByte() | (stream.ReadByte() << 8));
    }
```

Now I am getting the R-R interval as Int[] (Array) using the above code.

Now, what can I do to calculate HeartRate BPM using the R-R interval?

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.